# Creating a plist using Java

Tags: java, objective-c, serialization, plist

Is there an easy way to create a plist with Java? The result should be the same as serializing a dictionary in Objective C.

Comment: [com.dd.plist - A Java library for working with property lists](https://github.com/3breadt/dd-plist)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [PList](http://code.google.com/p/xmlwise/source/browse/trunk/src/main/xmlwise/Plist.java) class from [code.google.com/xmlwise](http://code.google.com/p/xmlwise) looks more promising to me.

Comment: If you prefer not to use 3rd party libraries, see my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11619384/974531

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any external Java libraries. Use the following steps:

1. Create an empty, stand-alone DOM document.

   ```
   DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
   DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
   DOMImplementation di = builder.getDOMImplementation();
   DocumentType dt = di.createDocumentType("plist",
     "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN",
     "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd");
   Document doc = di.createDocument("", "plist", dt);
   doc.setXmlStandalone(true);
   ```
2. Set plist version.

   ```
   Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
   root.setAttribute("version", "1.0");
   ```
3. Enter data.

   ```
   Element rootDict = doc.createElement("dict");
   root.appendChild(rootDict);
   Element sampleKey = doc.createElement("key");
   sampleKey.setTextContent("foo");
   rootDict.appendChild(sampleKey);
   Element sampleValue = doc.createElement("string");
   sampleValue.setTextContent("bar");
   rootDict.appendChild(sampleValue);
   ```
4. Create a transformer.

   ```
   DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(doc);
   TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
   Transformer t = tf.newTransformer();
   t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-16");
   t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.DOCTYPE_PUBLIC, dt.getPublicId());
   t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.DOCTYPE_SYSTEM, dt.getSystemId());
   t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
   t.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");
   ```
5. Write to file.

   ```
   StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
   StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(stringWriter);
   t.transform(domSource, streamResult);
   String xml = stringWriter.toString();
   System.out.println(xml); // Optionally output to standard output.
   OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream("example.plist");
   Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(stream, "UTF-16");
   writer.write(xml);
   writer.close();
   ```

You can then read such a file in Objective-C as described by the [Property List Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/QuickStartPlist/QuickStartPlist.html).

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.koders.com/java/fidEBB178A1E829A7A2C976F773C398EADD9480E424.aspx) you can find a PList class for creating PList very easily.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library: http://plist.sf.net/

It will write NSObjects to files and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

The existing answers look to complicated for simple cases. Here is a restricted shorter version:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;


public class PList {

    public static String toPlist(Map<String,String> map) {
        String s = "";
        s += "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
        s += "<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC \"-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN\" \"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd\">\n";
        s += "<plist version=\"1.0\">\n";
        s += "<dict>\n";

        for(Entry<String,String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            s += "  <key>" + entry.getKey() + "</key>\n";
            s += "    <string>" + entry.getValue() + "</string>\n";
        }

        s += "</dict>\n";
        s += "</plist>\n";
        return s;
    }

    public static void writePlistToFile(Map<String,String> map, File f) throws IOException {
        FileUtils.writeStringToFile(f, toPlist(map), "utf-8");
    }

}
```